# How to Tranfser huge amount of Files to slow USB Drive (dd, cp, rsync, 7z, tar)

Tags: files, usb, rsync, dd, file-copy

I have like 5GB of data and a very slow USB-Drive.

1. Should I use `dd`, `cp` or `rsync`?
2. Should I compress them first into for example `7z` / `tar` or not?

---

In short: What is the best way and the best practices to copy all those files to the USB-Drive?

---

---

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way is to compress them (on the same media where they are) and the transfer the archive to USB drive. Using this way you will have much less updates on USB for filesystem and less operations create/open/close (related to files).

About copy operation for me `cp` will be OK.

Comment: and which tool should I use? `dd`, `cp` or `rsync`?

Comment: @Pixelbog, for me `cp` should be OK